# Loki: cannot clear all notifications because menu is covered ... by notifications!

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel

once in a while I might get 200 email messages -- which leads to 200 notifications which must be closed one at a time. This is because the "Clear all notifications" menu item is always covered by notification bubbles. Anyone know how this could work? Perhaps give the menu higher priority/z-index than the notifications? Or even a command line argument to wingpanel as a workaround?

Many thanks.